# Determine the following factor group: $\mathbb{C}^* / \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Using the first isomorphism theorem, determine the following factor group:

$\mathbb{C}^* / P$ with $P = \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

How to find the factor group:

Find a surjective group homomorphism from the respective group whose kernel is the respective subgroup:

$\phi : \mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow G $ with ker$(\phi) = \{x \in \mathbb{C}^*, \phi(x) = $ neutral element of G$ \} =  P = \mathbb{R}_{>0} $

After that use the isomorphism theorem to describe the respective factor group down to isomorphism.

My problem here is that I can't find a suitable group G so that exactly the kernel is equal to P.

Which group G would fit here and what would be the corresponding mapping rule and the neutral element of G?

Comment: Here's a hint: what happens when you divide a non-zero complex number by its absolute value?

Comment: Writting $z=x+iy$, then $\displaystyle \psi (z) = \psi(x+iy)=\frac{x+iy}{|x+iy|}.$ If $z$ is real and positive, i.e, $y=0$ and $x>0$, then $\displaystyle \psi(z)=\frac{x}{|x|}=1$. I guess that is what you mean with your hint?

Comment: @clementine1001 What properties does $ \psi $ have? What is its range (codomain)? Is it perhaps something you were looking for?

Comment: @clementine1001 Yes, precisely. The map $\psi$ is a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbf{C}^\times$ to $S^1$ with kernel $\mathbf{R}_{>0}$.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is the circle group $\Bbb T$, denoted that way because it is a $1$-torus.

$\Bbb T$ is a group under the operation of complex multiplication,  with the role of the identity played by $z=1$.

The homomorphism is $\Bbb C^*\ni z\mapsto \dfrac z{\lvert z\rvert}\in\Bbb T$, and it's kernel is $P$.

This is an important example.